# How to trigger the system bell sound in VSCode from an extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I hear the system bell if I run in the console: `node -e "process.stdout.write('\x07')"`

I hear nothing If I have in my VSCode extension:

```
const vscode = require('vscode')
exports.activate = context => {
    process.stdout.write('\x07')
}
exports.deactivate = () => {}
```

How to trigger the system bell sound in VSCode from an extension?

Comment: For anyone visiting this in 2022, the issue is being tracked at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/47711